# Can't Override Equals method on Java when calling contains

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following funtion that checks if a List of codigos contains a single codigos object:

```
if (!concorrente.getJcodigoses().contains(cod)) 
        {
            return "redirect:" + referrer;
        }
```

I read that i need to Override the equals method like so:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        boolean isEqual= false;

        if (object != null && object instanceof Jcodigos)
        {
            isEqual = (this.id == ((Jcodigos) object).id);
        }



        return isEqual;
    }
```

I placed it in my Jcodigos.java class and i noticed that concorrente.getJcodigoses().contains(... never gets into my custom equals method...

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer:

I was missing the following method

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide an complmentary `hashCode()` method whenever providing an `equals()` method and visa-versa.

The reason for this is to fulfil the API contracts when interacting with the objects in collections. See the site for tips on creating the code [hashcode-equals](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html)

The [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) have more information about the requirements. As stated in the documentation about the equals method:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes.

Comment: While this is true in general, at least the JDK6/7 `ArrayList` does not care about the hash code and *should* call the overridden `equals()` method.

Comment: @Marvin, There was no mention of ArrayList. A LinkedList could have been used.

Comment: @BrettWalker: I just wanted to mention that it depends on the concrete implementation (`LinkedList` e.g. also relies on `equals()`) whether the `equals()` method gets called, not make an objection against always implementing `hashCode()` (and I gave you the +1 regardless) ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement `hashCode` as well.

Comment: While this is true in general, at least the JDK6/7 `ArrayList` does not care about the hash code and *should* call the overridden `equals()` method.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem :)